# Is it possible to automatically log every enter to a function?

Tags: php, debugging

Is there any switch in PHP that would allow to log every function that was entered? I mean, manual version:

```
function foo()
{
  echo "function foo entered.\n";
  ...
}
```

Of course I would like to "add" this `echo` as a switch, and a switch handled by PHP. Is it possible?

Comment: You could write a number to a file and increase the number each time the function is run, or do the same in a database

Comment: You could use call_user_function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to create kind of a wrapper to your function calls. You'd pass the function name to this wrapper, it would log the call and execute the function. But just for the sake of curiosity, why do you want to do such thing?

Comment: @Peter, I don't understand, I wrote **every** function, manual editing is no-go.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida, it is also no-go, it involves manual editing of the code. To look at logs, and find out what was called.

Comment: So sorry, but I don't know anything capable of doing what you want without 'manual editing of the code'. Maybe there is something, but I've never seen it. Good luck.

Comment: I read the question slightly wrong, but here's how I'd personally do it that involves minimal editing of all the code. Make a separate function called `log_functions` that puts an input into the database along with the current time, and from each of your other functions, just add a line to the start like `log_functions(__FUNCTION__)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) & [xdebug_start_function_monitor()](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `debug_print_backtrace();`

You can find examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

Comment: Than you but no, it does not give you the live log, and besides, I would have to add the call to it again -- manually in every function, which involves (a) manual work, (b) duplication of data.

Comment: I guess the answer is no then. Not without manual work. I guess you could use something like phptrace which tracks execution at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep the question open for a while, and I won't get any positive answer, that I will accept your answer for the account of the above comment.

Comment: I haven't used it much, but xdebug & xdebug_start_function_monitor() could help - https://xdebug.org/ & https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions

Comment: @RobGudgeon, great, could you please post your comment as regular answer (because you gave the solution).